# Meteor accounts-google internal server error, works on local but not on EC2

Tags: meteor, oauth, google-oauth, meteor-accounts

Hi Stackoverflow community, I have a problem with the google login of Meteor.

The login flow works perfectly fine in localhost but not in deploy.

I am getting the following error on Meteor's console:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Google. failed [400] {   "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch" }
at getTokens (packages/google/google_server.js:59:1)
at Object.ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne.service [as handleOauthRequest] (packages/google/google_server.js:10:1)
at OAuth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth2/oauth2_server.js:8:1)
at middleware (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:173:1)
at packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:146:1
```

This is the current checklist of my troubleshooting:

1.- Correct client id and client secret on db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration with loginStyle 'popup'

2.- redirect_uri set to the correct endpoint (http://example.com/_oauth/google) when the popup opens.

3.- redirect uri authorized on app's redirects on google's console

One of my observation is that if change the loginStyle to redirect instead of popup, after the google oauth redirects to my redirect_uri , my redirect_uri redirects again to localhost instead to the classic */_oauth/google window (Login completed. Click here to close this window.)

EDIT
Another error is showing up is:

```
Error in OAuth Server: redirectUrl (http://example.com/users) is not on the same host as the app (http://localhost:80/)
```

so the app is rejecting the redirectUrl (the domain has an A record to the elastic IP of my amazon ec2 instance) , I am running on port 80 only for testing purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see what the environment variable $ROOT_URL is set to. This can affect the expected redirect URL if not set correctly.

I use pop up with google oauth and use this string in my Authorized redirect URI:

```
http://example.org
http://example.org/_oauth/google?close
```

EDIT:

Even when I set the ROOT_URL as an environment variable, somehow Meteor was not using my ROOT_URL.

The solution was running meteor as:

```
$ ROOT_URL='https://example.org' meteor
```